# Uniformly continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a uniformly continuous function vanishing at $0$ bounded by $a|x|+c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14735/is-a-uniformly-continuous-function-vanishing-at-0-bounded-by-axc)

On the wikipedia page for [Modulus of Continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity), it states that for $f$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $\exists a,b>0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq a|x|+b$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Can someone please explain why this is?

Regards, MM.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes, that proof can be adapted accordingly I think. Shall I remove this post?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$f$ is uniformly continuous, thus given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|\leq \delta$ yields $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \epsilon$. By chosing any sequence $(x_k)_{k=0}^N$ such that $x_0=0$, $x_N=x$ and $|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq \delta$, we have
$$
|f(x)-f(0)|\leq \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} |f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)|\leq N\epsilon.
$$
But since $|x|/\delta\geq N$, you indeed obtain

$$
|f(x)|\leq (\epsilon/\delta)|x|+|f(0)|.$$

Comment: Oops, I've seen the Jonas Meyer's comment after posting.

Comment: There is a mistake.  It is not always possible to take $b=|f(0)|$.  For example, consider $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$, which is uniformly continuous, but for which $|f(x)|\leq a|x|$ is impossible.  I suggest revisiting the assumption that $|x|/\delta\geq N$.