# Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous. Then $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous. Then $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$ converges?

I have an example to $f(x)=x$. Which solves my question. But Can we say

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous. Then $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$ diverges? ..............(1)

I think we can.

It will be solved if we can prove that, $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous if $f(x)\leq cx+d$, where $c$ is a positive constant.......(2)

I don't the validity of the last statement. But I feel it is true. But I don't know.

So my questions: Can I prove (2), if not, please provide a counterexample and how do we prove (1)?

Comment: This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691143/show-that-there-are-a-b-geq-0-so-that-fx-leq-axb-forall-x-geq-0

Comment: Why does that $f(x)=x$ example solve your question?

Comment: Look at the question $\sum1/f(n)$ converge? The answer is no.

Comment: Also, your (2) makes no sense: you need $f(x)\le cx$ if $f$ is uniformly continuous, not the other way round. (Which is not true; but it's enough to show that $|f(x)|\le cx+d$ if $f$ is uniformly continuous.)

Comment: Yeah, I think I should edit that. I saw the link in the first comment. I think you probably wanted to say," Also, your (2) makes no sense: you need $f(x)≤cx$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous, not the other way round. (Which is not true; but it's enough to show that $|f(x)|≤cx+d$ if f is uniformly continuous.)

Comment: Your $f(x)=x$ example shows that $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$ doesn't always converge if $f$ is uniformly continuous. The real problem is surely to show that $\sum\frac{1}{f(n)}$ _never_ converges if $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: After I solved the above problem, then I convinced myself something much better can be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then $f(x)= O(x)$. This follows directly from definitions: if $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are be positive reals so that $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert \le \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x - y \lvert \le \delta$, then for all $x > 0$ we have

$$\lvert f(x) \rvert \le \lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert + \lvert f(0) \rvert \le \\ 
\lvert f(\delta) - f(0) \rvert + \lvert f(2 \delta) - f(\delta) \rvert + \ldots + \lvert f(x) - f(x - \left \lfloor \frac x \delta \right \rfloor \delta) \rvert + \lvert f(0) \rvert \\ \le \left \lceil \frac x \delta \right \rceil \epsilon + \lvert f(0) \rvert = O(x)$$

Now, this proves that $\sum \frac 1 {f(n)}$ cannot converge absolutely. Actually, it is also easy to see that, if $\lvert f(n)\rvert$ converges to infinity along natural $n$ (as must happen if our series is to converge), then $f$ must be constantly negative or positive after a certain value. Thus, the series would have to converge absolutely if it were to converge at all. Your suspicion is right; $\sum \frac 1{f(n)}$ always diverges.