# Prove that there exists $M>0$ such that for every $x\geq 1$ it satisfies $|f(x)|\leq Mx$

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a uniformly continuous function in the interval $[1,\infty)=I$.

Prove that there exists $M>0$ such that for every $x\geq 1$ it satisfies $|f(x)|\leq Mx$.
**My attempt:**

Let $\epsilon>0$. there exist $\delta>0$ such that for every $x,y\in I$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$(because f is uniformly continuous).

I know it's not much, but that's all I've got.

Comment: See the general case (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691143/show-that-there-are-a-b-geq-0-so-that-fx-leq-axb-forall-x-geq-0)

Comment: @CunyiNan Does it mean I can choose $b=0$ and $f(1)$ instead of $f(0)$? If so, can you explain why can I choose this $f(1)$, and how did you find this question, becuase I searched for similar questions, and couldn't find any.

Comment: Do similar steps in the link I mentioned, you will find $|f(x)|\leq ax+b$ where $a,b\geq0$, here $b$ contains value $|f(1)|$ plus other something. Then choose another number $c>a$, the right term becomes smaller than $cx$ i.e. the target $M$ we want to find.

Comment: You mention $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then you say that $f$ is continuous on the interval $[1,\infty)$ . Shouldn't you be saying that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$

Comment: It wont help for this question.

Comment: Extend $f$ by $\forall x\in[0,1),\;f(x)=f(1)$ and apply the "[general case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691143)" linked above by @CunyiNan. There exists $a,b\ge0$ such that $\forall x\ge0,\;|f(x)|\le ax+b.$ Then choose $M\ge a+b$ and you get $\forall x\ge1,\;ax+b\le Mx.$