# Example of a function which is non-lipschitz but satisfies some weaker notion of linear growth

Tags: real-analysis

What is an example of a function which is not lipschitz but satisfies the following weaker notion of linear growth

$$f(x) < K(1+x) \forall x, K > 0$$

along with being continuous

Comment: Maybe $f(x)=-1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$ ?

Comment: The fractional part of $x$, $f(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$?

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14735/is-a-uniformly-continuous-function-vanishing-at-0-bounded-by-axc

Answer (score 0):

Since the [Lipshitz condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) is a strong form of uniform continuity, any discontinous function will not be Lipschitz.

The estimate $f(x) \lt K(1+x)$ tells us nothing about continuity, only about "growth" of the function being limited, at least as viewed for positive $x \gt 0$.  So one easily fabricates examples like ones given in Comments above for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and a bit of fudging would make those work on the entire real line.

A formula that works everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous function $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}$ with $K=1$.  Thus $f(x) \lt x \lt 1+x$.

**Added in response to change in Question:**

A continuous function that satisfies the growth condition with $K=1$, but fails to be Lipshitz because of points with arbitrarily steep slope is:

$$ f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \sqrt{1-(1-\{x\})^2} - 1 $$

where $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.  Again we have $f(x) \lt 1+x$.

Comment: I want a continuous function with such property.