# Question about convergence of a series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

First of all, Happy new year!

Sorry for the non specific title, There was not enough space for a good description.

I have been trying to find a example for the following function $f$:

1. Does there exists a uniformly continuous function $f$ at $[-∞,+∞]  $Such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^3}$ will diverge?
2. Assuming theres such function $f$ as above, Can we find another function such that the Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{2^n}$ will diverge?

I am positive theres no such function $f$ for the second question, But im not sure how to disprove this statement, And I was not able to find such $f$ for my first question, Which im not even sure If such function exists.

The fastest growing  uniformly continous $f$  I can think of is $f(x) = ax$, Which is not enough.

Any hints will be appericiated.

Comment: Nu such function exists. There exist $a,b>0$  such that $|f(x)|\leq a+b|x|$ for all $x$. Prove this using uniform continuity.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14735/is-a-uniformly-continuous-function-vanishing-at-0-bounded-by-axc

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes My bad, Comment was deleted.